# Syntax aware selection in XCode?

Tags: xcode, text, macros

Since moving to XCode I am desperately missing a text macro I have used in many other editors which I use all the time. Basically what it does is that everytime you invoke it, it selects text in an expanding scope. Here is IntelliJ's definition of the functionality:

> Syntax aware selection
>   Ctrl+W (select word) in the editor selects a word at the caret and then selects expanding areas of the source code. For example, it may select a method name, then the expression that calls this method, then the whole statement, then the containing block, etc.

Any way to duplicate this functionality in XCode?

Comment: I'm also looking for this, did you ever find the answer?

Comment: Also want this... it exists in Eclipse, IntelliJ, etc. It's possible to install even in emacs. Why not Xcode :(

Answer (score 2):

Xcode preferences (Cmd+,) -> Key Bindings -> Text Key Bindings -> "Select Word"

Comment: The question is not only select word, is syntax-aware expand functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't have it.

You can use [AppCode](https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/) instead. I bought it for that reason and many others.

Comment: It's a shame jetbrain is giving up on appcode, Apple's editor has been too weak in development convenience for so many years, and its closed nature makes you have to put up with it